# How to Fix Module Not Installed Error in BB10 IDE

Tags: ide, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, blackberry-qnx

Is it possible to fix module not installed error in BB10 IDE? Attached is screenshot of error to explain it a bit.

Note: There is a similar question on SO which is kind of asking the same question (still not found correct answer yet) - [blackberry cascades mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359087/blackberry-cascades-mapview)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a currently a known issue with the QML preview in the Momentics IDE.  It only supports the core cascades components.

I answered a similar question here:
[blackberry 10 Unresolved inclusion <QObject>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953916/blackberry-10-unresolved-inclusion-qobject/14472577#14472577)